# Don't clear calendar reminders on iphone when clearing all notifications

Tags: iphone, calendar, notifications

I recently migrated from Android to iOS 10.2. One big problem I have are notifications, I receive hundreds of valid notifications each day (emails, messages, calendar reminders, etc) and I want to remove all notifications except calendar reminders. In android they were grouped by app so I was able to simply remove all emails for example. But now I either have to manually remove each email or I have to "clear all", which also clears calendar reminders.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have  you tried going to `Settings -> Notifications` and disabling notifications from every app except the calendar?

Comment: I mentioned "valid notifications", which means I am expecting notifications from all those apps and I need to have them enabled

Comment: You also stated "I want to remove all notifications except calendar reminders".  I was responding based on the info you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot clear all notifications without clearing reminders as well (by the way, on iOS they are just called Reminders). If you want to selectively clear notifications, you'll have to do that manually, just the way you described it. It's either one or all.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to prevent most apps from appearing in the Notification Center altogether.

Open **Settings** → **Notifications** and for every app you don’t want in the Notification Center, toggle **Show in Notification Center** *Off*.

You will still receive notifications as normal for those apps, but you won’t need to clear them out of your Notification Center.

I do this for apps that show a **Badge Icon** since I’m reminded of their notifications right from the home screen anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately disabling notifications for apps doesn't help me as I actually need to have all those notifications visible until I check (most of the times not one by one) & remove them